# Applescript how to make file list and move files with certain names

Tags: file, scripting, applescript, automator, finder

I want to make a script that takes a list of names, and moves certain files that have the similar names to the list, into another folder.

To break it down, I have a folder with a few files "appleClient2016.pdf", "fruitClient2016.pdf", "pearClient2016.pdf"

Now I have a list of "appleSept", "pearSept"
I want to move my list into another folder.

I need a script that recognizes appleSept and appleClient2016.rtf both have apple in the string and will move the pdf into another folder. Also it can only move pdf files.

I am very new to applescript but here is my attempt

```
set listOfFruits to {"appleSept", "pearSept"}

 tell application "Finder"

if folder "moveTest1" contains listOfFruits then
    move (every file of folder "moveTest1" whose name is listOfFruits) to folder "moveTest2"
end if

 end tell
```

I know I have a few syntax errors here, but I think you get the idea of what im going for. 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about two things regarding `listOfFruits` which is a list of **strings**.

1. A folder never contains a list of strings it contains a list of files or folders (*contains listOfFruits*).
2. A file has never a name which is a list of strings (*whose name is listOfFruits*).

Basically it is not needed to check 1. with an if clause.

To check if a name is **in** a list of strings you have to write `is in` rather than `is`.
To understand the syntax `is in`: The expression `a is in {a, b, c}` is the same as `{a, b, c} contains a`

```
    set listOfFruits to {"appleSept", "pearSept"}

    tell application "Finder"
        move (every file of folder "moveTest1" whose name is in listOfFruits) to folder "moveTest2"
    end tell
```